# Why isn't subprocess.Popen.kill() doing anything?

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions

I am following the Google Cloud Functions python testing example here:
https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/testing/test-http

```py
import os
import subprocess
import uuid

import requests
from requests.packages.urllib3.util.retry import Retry


def test_args():
    name = str(uuid.uuid4())
    port = os.getenv('PORT', 8080)  # Each functions framework instance needs a unique port

    process = subprocess.Popen(
      [
        'functions-framework',
        '--target', 'hello_http',
        '--port', str(port)
      ],
      cwd=os.path.dirname(__file__),
      stdout=subprocess.PIPE
    )

    # Send HTTP request simulating Pub/Sub message
    # (GCF translates Pub/Sub messages to HTTP requests internally)
    BASE_URL = f'http://localhost:{port}'

    retry_policy = Retry(total=6, backoff_factor=1)
    retry_adapter = requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter(
      max_retries=retry_policy)

    session = requests.Session()
    session.mount(BASE_URL, retry_adapter)

    name = str(uuid.uuid4())
    res = session.post(
      BASE_URL,
      json={'name': name}
    )
    assert res.text == 'Hello {}!'.format(name)

    # Stop the functions framework process
    process.kill()
    process.wait()
```

After running `pytest` against this test file, the test passes and the code exits nearly immediately, but it doesn't appear to have killed the process:

```
± ps -ef | grep functions
thoraxe    11661    1985 49 20:30 pts/0    00:00:02 /home/thoraxe/.pyenv/versions/3.9.13/envs/avogadro-trainer-3-9-13/bin/python3.9 /home/thoraxe/.pyenv/versions/3.9.13/envs/avogadro-trainer-3-9-13/bin/functions-framework --target train --port 8080
thoraxe    11684   11661  0 20:30 pts/0    00:00:00 /home/thoraxe/.pyenv/versions/3.9.13/envs/avogadro-trainer-3-9-13/bin/python3.9 /home/thoraxe/.pyenv/versions/3.9.13/envs/avogadro-trainer-3-9-13/bin/functions-framework --target train --port 8080
```

I'm using Python 3.9.13 in a virtual environment on Fedora.

As this is sample code from Google, I'd expect it to work, but something is definitely not working here. Can someone suggest what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like `functions-framework` forks a child to run `functions-frame`, then the main process exits.

Comment: @barmar `ps -e` doesn't show the full process name. It is definitely `functions-framework` I run `ps -ef`. I'll update the post.

Comment: Put a long `time.sleep()` call before `process.kill()` and run `pstree` while it's sleeping to see the process tree. I think you'll see that there are nested processes.

Comment: @barmar I think the problem is that when the assert fails (test fails), python immediately exits, so the remaining steps are not executed. I added a `print` after the `assert` and it never printed any output. I think I need to change a setting to make the program continue after failed `assert`

Comment: It looks like https://github.com/okken/pytest-check could be a potential solution here. I need to TIAS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a Python assertion fails, the program exits immediately and does not continue. The kill/wait are never actually executed unless the test is successful. This is a major bummer because the function framework will continue to run in the background and new code changes aren't apparently picked up on subsequent `pytest` runs.

Using a different wrapper framework like https://github.com/okken/pytest-check solves the problem because all steps will be performed, even if there are failures.

However, note that legitimate Python failures/errors/explosions will still result in the functions framework not properly exiting.